# Powershell Expand Property and Add Column

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to create a script that will output the HTTP headers from an Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet along with the URL for the request.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com"
$a = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Headers
$a
```

That gives me the following output:

```
Key              Value                        
---              -----                        
Vary             Accept-Encoding              
X-Cache          HIT, HIT from 10.193.64.18   
Proxy-Connection Keep-Alive                   
Content-Length   1270                         
Cache-Control    max-age=604800               
Content-Type     text/html; charset=UTF-8     
Date             Tue, 19 Feb 2019 16:02:56 GMT
Expires          Tue, 26 Feb 2019 16:02:56 GMT
ETag             "1541025663+ident"           
Last-Modified    Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
Server           ECS (dca/246E)               
Via              SWG
```

Now, my goal is to eventually loop through a text file with URLs and output to a CSV for further analysis.

To have useful data, I need to have the URLs of the request as an additional column for every one of the headers keys/values.

I've spent a couple hours searching for, and trying, different examples online without much success.

***EDITED***
Figured it out based on some additional searching:

```
$workingdirectory = $PSScriptRoot + '\'
$urlpath = $workdirectory + 'URLs.txt'
$savepath = $workingdirectory + 'output.csv'
$results = @()

foreach($url in Get-Content -Path $urlpath){
    $ht = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Headers
    $keys = $ht.keys
    foreach ($key in $keys) {
        $results += New-Object psobject -Property @{'Name'=$key;'Value'=$ht[$key];'URL'=$url}
        }
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path $savepath -NoTypeInformation
```

Which will give you something like (when presented as a table):

```
URL                       Name                             Value                                                                                                                                        
---                       ----                             -----                                                                                                                                        
http://www.example.com/   Vary                             Accept-Encoding                                                                                                                              
http://www.example.com/   X-Cache                          HIT, HIT from 10.193.64.18                                                                                                                   
...                                                                                                                         
http://www.microsoft.com/ Pragma                           no-cache                                                                                                                                     
http://www.microsoft.com/ X-UA-Compatible                  IE=Edge;chrome=1                                                                                                                             
...
```

Comment: it looks like `$A` will be a hashtable. you can simply `.Add()` the $URL to that as another `key:value` pair & then convert it to a custom object for sending to `Export-CSV`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to get you started.  Study the code, debug in VSCode or ISE, and search for help `Get-Help` for new concepts.  There are ways to optimize this code, but for learning purposes, expanding each step is sometimes helpful.

```
$uri = @(
    "http://microsoft.com"
    "http://google.com"
    "http://yahoo.com"
    "http://twitter.com"
    )

$out = @()

foreach ($u in $uri)
{
    $h = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $u | Select -ExpandProperty Headers

    # create hash table/dictionary
    $o = [ordered]@{}

    # add Uri
    $o.Add('Uri', $u)

    # add each Key/Value from $h
    foreach ($k in $h.Keys)
    {
        $o.Add($k, $h[$k])
    }

    # Create psobject from the dictionary
    $p = New-Object psobject -Property $o

    # inefficient to store in $p, but you can see $p in debugger
    $out += $p
}

# create csv
$c = $out | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

# save to csv file?
$c | Out-File -FilePath e:\test.csv

# view csv
notepad.exe E:\test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the basis for this:

```
$URLs = get-content -path "URLs.txt"
$Output = @()

$Output = foreach ($URL in $URLs) {
    $a = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Headers
    $objA = [pscustomobject]$a
    $objA | Add-Member -Type noteproperty -name "URL" -value $URL
    $objA
}

$Output | export-csv -path "CSVFile.csv" -notypeinformation
```